# How to setState after code has been compiled Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to build a chat app that is using SQFLite to store data. There's only one bug where I can find an answer to. The bug is that setState has been called first and then it will compile the rest of the code. Here is how I did it can you help me out?

main.dart

```
class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Text'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 20,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .8,
                child: Container(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                    // This is where the messages are being loaded and displayed
                    future: messages(dbName),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return snapshot.data;
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 12,
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (text) async {
                          print(text);
                          message = text;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: MaterialButton(
                        child: Text(''),
                        onPressed: () {
                           setState(() {
                             // This is where the problem has to be fixed.
                             var typing;
                             connectToServer(typing, message);
                             // Trying to call setState once again but it doesn't fix the issue
                               setState(
                                 () {},
                                );
                              })
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

server.dart

```
void connectToServer(typing, message) async {
  // Store message to SQFlite.
  if (message != null) {
    sendMessage() async {
      // Store message in SQFlite
      var locDb = await openDatabase('chats.db');
      String dbName = emailUser + friendName;
      //await locDb.execute('DROP TABLE $dbName');
      await locDb.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $dbName (_id INTEGER, sender TEXT, reciever TEXT, message TEXT, timestamp TEXT, recieved TEXT)',
      );
      await locDb.rawInsert(
        'INSERT INTO $dbName(_id, sender, reciever, message, timestamp, recieved) VALUES("$_id", "$emailUser", "$friendName", "$message", "$timeStamp", "FALSE")',
      );
      messages(dbName);
      await locDb.close();
    }

    return sendMessage();
  }
}
```

getMessages.dart

```
class MessageClass {
  final String id;
  final String emailUser;
  final String friendName;
  final String message;
  final String timeStamp;
  final String recieved;

  MessageClass({
    this.id,
    this.emailUser,
    this.friendName,
    this.message,
    this.timeStamp,
    this.recieved,
  });
}

Future<void> messages(dbName) async {
  var locDb = await openDatabase('chats.db');

  List<Map> messages = await locDb.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $dbName');

  return Container(
    height: 200,
    child: ListView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: List.generate(
        messages.length,
        (i) {
          var _message = MessageClass(
            id: messages[i]['id'],
            emailUser: messages[i]['emailUser'],
            friendName: messages[i]['friendName'],
            message: messages[i]['message'],
            timeStamp: messages[i]['timeStamp'],
            recieved: messages[i]['recieved'],
          );
          return GridTile(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                _message.recieved.toString() == 'FALSE'
                    ? Spacer()
                    : Container(),
                Text(
                  _message.message.toString(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I know that the code is really long but maybe you have found another method than setState. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onPressed: () async {
         //setState(() {});
         
              var typing;
              await connectToServer(typing, message);

              setState(() {});
           
         },
```

Don't forget async await. And use one setState.